# PHP making simple admin for php script

Tags: php

So, I've a little system which generates pretty permalinks using htaccess.

PHP side of the things I handle in the following manner:

```
if (!$_GET) {
    //
    $page = "home";
    $page_title = "General Site Title";
    include ("template/index.php");
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "profile") {
    //
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        //
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            include ("template/404.php");
        exit();
        //
    } else {
        //
        $page = "profile";
        $page_title = "User Profile";
        include ("template/profile.php");
        //
    }
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "words") {
    //
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        //
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            include ("template/404.php");
        exit();
        //
    } else {
        //
        $page = "words";
        $page_title = "Words Page";
        include ("template/words.php");
    }
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "contacts") {
    //
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        //
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            include ("template/404.php");
        exit();
        //
    } else {
        //
        $page = "contacts";
        $page_title = "User Contacts";
        include ("template/contacts.php");
        //
    }
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "about") {
    //
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        //
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            include ("template/404.php");
        exit();
        //
    } else {
        //
        $page = "about";
        $page_title = "About Page";
        include ("template/about.php");
        //
    }
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "verify") {
    //

    //
} else {
    //
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include ("template/404.php");
    exit();
    //
}
```

As you can see there is allot of repeating code. How would you go about making this admin panel friendly? What I want to do is have an array of pages with data that will generate this if else statement. Is it possible?

Ideally something like this:

```
array("page" => "home", "page_title" => "blah", "template" => "index.php", "has_subpage" => false);
```

or should I stick to the way I'm doing things atm?

Comment: get rid of all those `//` lines first!

Comment: The use of [`case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) could be an option.

Comment: @popnoodles you don't like them? :)

Comment: +1 @Fred-ii- for suggesting case. You're already doing some exit() there which are unnecessary in the if/else statements.

Comment: In fact, you could completely remove all of the 404 generating lines and include them at the very end case. AND you could throw those into a function, and then you'd simply call something like throwFour04();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following structure:

```
$pages = array('profile' => array('title' => 'User Profile',
                                  'include' => 'template/profile.php'),
               'words' => array('title' => 'Words Page',
                                'include' => 'template/words.php'),
               ...);

// Set defaults if no parameters supplied
$page = "home";
$page_title = "General Site Title";
$include_file = "template/index.php";

// Override from parameters
if (isset($_GET['page'], $pages[$_GET['page']])) {
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            include ("template/404.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $page_title = $pages[$page]['title'];
        $include_file = $pages[$page]['template'];
    }
}

include ($include_file);
```

Comment: What about homepage with this code, I will not have root dir. if (!$_GET)

Comment: You would include home in the array. I've updated my answer to show how to use that (without duplicate code).

Comment: I added my own defaulting in a slightly different way, but putting home in the array is also a reasonable way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$pages = array(
  'words' => array('title' => 'Words', 'file' => 'includes/words.php'),
  'contact' => array('title' => 'Contact', 'file' => 'includes/contact.php'),
  'profile' => array('title' => 'Profile', 'file' => 'includes/profile.php',
    'subpages' => array('subpage1' => array( 'title' => 'foo', 'file' => 'bar'))
  ),
);

if( isset($_GET['page']) && isset($pages[$_GET['page']]) ) {
  $page = $pages[$_GET['page']];
  if( ! isset($_GET['subpages']) ) {
    $title = $page['title'];
    include($page['file']);
  } else if( isset($page['subpages']) && isset($page['subpages'][$_GET['subpage']]) ) {
    $page = $page['subpages'][$_GET['subpage']];
    $title = $page['title'];
    include($page['file']);
  } else {
    // 404 code here
  }
} else {
  // 404 code here
}
```

Comment: @SandroDzneladze 1. Wat? 2. Use `isset($_GET['varname'])` unless you like 'Undefined Index' warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch and case but you'd still be left with a lot of duplicate code. Or you could use an array.

```
$pages=array(
    'home'=>array('title'=>'Home', 'has_subpage'=>false),
    'profile'=>array('title'=>'User Profile', 'has_subpage'=>false),
    'words'=>array('title'=>'Words Page', 'has_subpage'=>false),
    'contacts'=>array('title'=>'User Contacts', 'has_subpage'=>false),
    // etc
);

// if no page is set, use "home"
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) $_GET['page']='home';

if (array_key_exists($_GET['page'], $pages)){
    if ($_GET['subpage']) {
        die404();
    }else{
        $page=$pages[$_GET['page']];
        $page_title = $page['title']; 
        include ("template/".$_GET['page'].".php");
    }
}else{
    die404();
}

function die404(){
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    include ("template/404.php"); 
    exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like (warning! untested!)

```
if (!$_GET) {
    $page = "home";
    $page_title = "General Site Title";
    include ("template/index.php");
} 
else if ($_GET)
{
    $pages = array('profile' => 'User Profile', 'words' => 'Words Page', 'contacts' => 'User Contacts', 'about' => 'About Page', 'verify' => 'Verify');
    foreach ($pages as $page => $page_title)
    {
        if (($_GET['page'] == $page) && (!$_GET['subpage']))
            include ("template/$page.php");
    }
}
else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include ("template/404.php");
}
```